# Is it correct to say "She held the scooter backwards"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Look at this picture

[image]

A child is holding a scooter like the picture above.

Is it correct to say "**She held the scooter backwards**" or "**She pushed the scooter backwards**"?

Comment: If someone said *She held the scooter backwards* or *He's holding his motorbike backwards*, I wouldn't have a clue what they meant. You'd have to explain the situation using more and/or different words. Interestingly, my first attempt at something clearer - *...by the handlebars, **facing towards** him/herself,* would quite naturally use ***forwards*** rather than ***backwards*** anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be correct to say "She held the scooter backwards" but if the scooter is moving, it would be much more usual to say "She pushed the scooter backwards".

The grammar of "She held the scooter backwards" is perfectly fine, but I would slightly struggle to justify the logic of the statement - that's a perfectly normal way to hold a scooter, and the statement has a strong implication of doing something wrong, so I might prefer "She held the scooter back-to-front".

Comment: British says "back to front" and American says "backwards"